# What's inside the ActorItr iterator variable and what * ActorItr returns?

Tags: c++, iterator

In Unreal Engine C++ programming

```
for (TActorIterator ActorItr(GetWorld()); ActorItr; ++ActorItr) 
{ // Same as with the Object Iterator, access the subclass instance with the * or -> operators.
    AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = *ActorItr; 
    ClientMessage(ActorItr->GetName()); 
    ClientMessage(ActorItr->GetActorLocation().ToString()); 
} 

AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = *ActorItr
```

In the code above Mesh is a pointer of type `AStaticMeshActor`. Therefore you must receive a memory address. But my doubts is why use the *operator? why not just use `ActorItr` or `& ( *ActorItr)`?

```
AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = ActorItr ----->Error

AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = &(*ActorItr) ------>Error
```

Does `*ActorItr` return the address of the pointed object or returns the object pointed to by `Actoritr`? Why does unreal engine will assign the object itself to a variable that expects to receive a memory address?

Thank you...

Comment: It looks like `TActorIterator` is a class template, not a type, so that code isn't valid unless it's something like within a member of a class derived from a `TActorIterator` specialization.  So this very much depends on context which you have not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActorItr` is clearly a container iterator of some kind, and `GetWorld()` returns a container of `AStaticMeshActor*` pointers.

`*ActorItr` dereferences the iterator to access (a reference to) the actual container element, which happens to be an `AStaticMeshActor*` pointer in your example.

You cannot assign the `ActorItr` itself to `Mesh`, because the iterator is itself not an `AStaticMeshActor*` pointer, only the element it refers to is.

`&(*ActorItr)` also fails because that is dereferencing the iterator to get an `AStaticMeshActor*` pointer, then taking the address of that pointer, thus producing an `AStaticMeshActor**` pointer.

`ActorItr->` similarly also dereferences the iterator to access the underlying container element, so you are calling `GetName()` and `GetActorLocation()` on the `AStaticMeshActor` object being pointed to.

All input/output iterators are dereferencable by `operator*`, and input iterators are also dereferencable by `operator->`.

Comment: Great!! Very well explained .. I have knowledge about the theory and practice of pointers and now I have consolidated the knowledge. about iterator ... thanks!